# Terraform For Expression and more than one list

Tags: for-loop, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to use following for expression to create CloudWatch dashboard using TF 0.13.7
Variables:

```
variable "redis_replicas" {
  type = list(map(string))
  default = [
    {
      name   = "test-eucentral1-redis-001"
      region = "eu-central-1"
    },

locals {
  replicas = [for i in var.redis_replicas: i.name]
  regions = [for i in var.redis_replicas: i.region]
```

resources

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_dashboard" "cloudwatch_db_redis" {
  dashboard_name = "Redis-Performance"
  dashboard_body = jsonencode({
    widgets : concat(local.body1)
  })
}

  body1 = [ 
    {
      height = 6
      properties = {
        metrics = [ for replica in local.replicas : 
          [
            {
              expression = "m1"
              id         = "e1"
            },
          ], # getting error here 
          [
            "AWS/ElastiCache",
            "ClusterBasedCmds",
            "CacheClusterId",
            replica,
          ],
        ]
        view    = "timeSeries"
      }
      type  = "metric"
    }
  ]
```

Using

```
metrics = [for instance in var.redis_replicas : [
[],
[],
]
```

Plan works but apply is failing.

```
Error: Putting dashboard failed: InvalidParameterInput: The dashboard body is invalid, there are 50 validation errors:
[
  {
    "dataPath": "/widgets/9/properties/metrics/0/0",
    "message": "Invalid metric field type, only \"String\" type is allowed"
  },
```

Any idea how to combine those two?
It works if I do for in body but then I have different graphs for different replica.

Comment: "apply is failing. " is not specific. What errors do you get? Also what exactly are `var.redis_replicas` and `local.replicas`. Sadly your question lacks details and is unclear.

Comment: Updated missing parts